# merging a small world graph and a graph with high clustering but the corresponding diameter is too high

Tags: graph, p2p, topology

I have an algorithm that creates a mesh topology with high clustering and it's diameter is small ( small world graph). Also, I have another one that creates a graph with high clustering but the corresponding diameter is too high.

Now I want to merge these two graph with common(maybe same) nodes, but I don't know how.

I want to know the what are the properties(especially diameter and clustering coefficient) of that graph.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the desired properties of the merged graph so that we can suggest a merging algorithm? Equivalently, what is the merging algorithm so that we can elaborate its properties?

Comment: From what I understand, the merging algorithm should be a union. That's still to generic. A disjoint union will produce a graph with an infinite diameter.

Comment: my desired properties of the merged graph is small diameter.
i have no idea about the merging algorithm right now .
I'm working on it.i appreciate any comments.